# Check if a foreach loop with a keyvaluepair is the last item and then do something in c#

Tags: c#, foreach, blazor-webassembly

I have a specific question relating a foreach loop in C# and Blazor Web Assembly.

This is my foreach loop containing a keyvaluepair:
`

```
@foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in detail.Years2Value.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
     {
      <td colspan="1"><input type="text" class="radius form-control" style="background-color:transparent; border:0.1px" readonly="readonly" value=@pair.Value></td>
      }
      <td colspan="1" class="border-left border-right"></td>
```

`
I want to display all values in a range and in a Region. After each region it should create an empty row to make it look better and more organized. Thats why I am adding a td after the foreach.
This creates following problem: --> See Picture below!
after the last foreach in my last Region is done, I don't want to create a new td but I don´t know how to achieve this.

[image: Picture showing the problem]

If I just delete the line of code with the td after the foreach then all regions will stick more or less together and it don´t look so good anymore because the missing "separation" of each region.

Is there a way to break the foreach only after the 3rd region is done and then don´t do the new td with an if sentence or something similar?

I hope you guys can help me here. Sorry if there is any information missing or something is not clear. I will try to explain it again if something is not clear.

Thank you

Comment: Outside of your foreach loop how are you constructing your table element, meaning...have you got <table><tr>and then start your <td> inside of the <tr> block ?

Comment: @AbdushSamadMiah yes correct, I have a Table and I start my td inside a tr block.

Comment: Is using of "for" loop instead of "foreach" a possiblity? This way you can compare if current iteration value is the same as the length of the array and figure out it is the last item.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have never worked with "for" before, I need to check how to reconstruct my code to compare the current iteration with the length of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your example well:

You could use for-loop and iterate through the items with index like the following.

```
@*Loop through all the KeyValuePairs in the Dictionary<int,string> *@
@for (int i = 1; i < orderedYearsToValue.Count(); i++)
{
    <td colspan="1">
        @*Select element and its value at the current index*@
        <input type="text" class="radius form-control" style="background-color:transparent; border:0.1px" readonly="readonly" value=@orderedYearsToValue.ElementAt(i).Value>
    </td>
    @*If the current index is not at the last item, add an empty line *@
    @if (i != orderedYearsToValue.Count()-1)
    {
        <td colspan="1" class="border-left border-right"></td>
    }
} 
      
@code {

  private Dictionary<int, string> orderedYearsToValue;
  
  ... your code
  
  private void OrderValues() {
    orderedYearsToValue = detail.Years2Value.OrderBy(x => x.Key);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE after update of the original code:**

The empty TD is done after every region. Therefore the for-loop should be done on the top level and TD only added after region is finished, instead of the nested loop.
Simplified code (use the logic from above):

```
for (int i = 0; i < myOrderedCountries.Count(); i++) 
{
    if(detail != null) 
    {
        if(isSpecialist) 
        {
            foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> in myOrderedYearsToValue) 
            {
                <td colspan="1"><input type="text" ...></td>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> in myOrderedYearsToValue) 
            {
                <td colspan="1"><input type="different text" ...></td>
            }
        }
        
        if(i < myOrderedCountries.Count() - 1) {
            <td colspan="1" class="border-left border-right"></td>
        }
    }
}
```

and even nicer would be to move the if part into the nested for-loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myOrderedCountries.Count(); i++) 
{
    if(detail != null) 
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> in myOrderedYearsToValue) 
        {
            if(isSpecialist) 
            {
                <td colspan="1"><input type="text" ...></td>
            }
            else 
            {
                <td colspan="1"><input type="different text" ...></td>
            }
        
        if(i < myOrderedCountries.Count() - 1) {
            <td colspan="1" class="border-left border-right"></td>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code

```html
int i = 1;
@foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in detail.Years2Value.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
{
    <td colspan="1"><input type="text" class="radius form-control" style="background-color:transparent; border:0.1px" readonly="readonly" value=@pair.Value></td>
    if(i < detail.Years2Value.Count)
    {
        <td colspan="1" class="border-left border-right"></td>
    }
    i++;
}
```